# coffeescript .on "change" duplicate ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I have used .on "change" event to update a record in the text field named as "form_name"

This "form_name" text field behave like a search box as well as drop down see below image

[text field image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU0lZ.png)

when i type a form_name it will search for a form name then i select the name of the form record is getting saved twice.

coffeescript ->

```
$(document).on "change", ".form-requirement-name", (e) ->
self = $(this)
id = self.data("id")
value = self.val()
request = $.post("/programs/#{id}/form_requirement_name", {"form_name": value})
request.done (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
  toastr.success('Form action updated.')
```

form_requirement_name.controller.rb

```
def form_requirement_name
form_name = params[:form_name]
if is_temp?(params[:id])
  session[:temp_form_list_rule][:form_id] = form_name
  save_temp_form_list_rule
  respond_to do |format|
    if @form_list_rule.form_id.present?
      format.json {render json: @form_list_rule}
    else
      format.json {head :ok}
    end
  end
end
```

end

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you check if you're getting two ajax calls in one selection or one ajax calls but two save actions?

Comment: @EJ2015 i am getting two ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following before ajax call:

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you should bind on `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` event instead of `change`.